# UITableView Delete Button doesn't disappears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableViewCell and configured it that editing is enabled.
Everything works fine but my problem is that the delete confirmation doesn't disappear when the round delete button (the circle with a "|") is pressed  the second time.

Does anybody know why this could happen?

[EDIT]

I narrowed it down to a method which is called every second and in that method I call beginUpdates and endUpdates on the editable UITableView. Does anybody knows a workaround?

Comment: At least can you show your code ? This question is too abstract.

Comment: You need to explain your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to take a stab in the dark... You probably are setting `editing` to true and then not setting it back to false. Make sure whatever method you call to set the value of `editing` reverses its value each time it's called.

```
- (void)setTableDelete 
{
    bool temp = !myTableView.editing;
    [myTableView setEditing:temp animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: No it should be in editing mode just the delete button should dissappear after tapping the round "|" indicator

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Dashboard *dashboard = [dashboards dashboardAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        NSLog(@"delete");
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        NSLog(@"insert");
    }

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Reloading the rows is key.

Comment: You misunderstand me, the delete button is not yet pressed just the round "|" indicator to show the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by avoiding the use of beginUpdates & endUpdates methods if tableView is in edit mode, instead i update the cells manually if edit mode is YES.